# SSL - Server does not send back ChangeCipherSpec

Tags: openssl

I have a server-client application, which runs properly on my local. However when I deploy it into the production environment, which means the server is deployed on a remote machine, the SSL handshake is failed. The following is what I get from openssl:

```
openssl s_client -msg -tls1_2 -connect <host>:<port> -CAfile <pem file>

C->S: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0122], ClientHello
S->C: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0051], ServerHello
S->C: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0335], Certificate

depth=1 C = US, ST = Unknown, L = Unkown, O = Unknown, OU = Unknown, CN = QATestCA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Unknown, O = Unknown, CN = d-linux64-07
verify return:1

S->C: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 019d], ServerKeyExchange
S->C: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0004], ServerHelloDone
C->S: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0096], ClientKeyExchange
C->S: TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
C->S: TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
write:errno=104
```

As you can see, the server does not send back ChangeCipherSpec to the client and I got Connection Rest exception in my application. 
Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thanks!